# prepend between <li> and </li> before <span> in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i have the following code

```
 <div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div>
<span class="folder">level 1</span>
<ul style="display: none;">
```

I wants to prepend the element

to span.
so the result would be

```
 <div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div>
<li><span class="folder">level 1</span></li>
<ul style="display: none;">
```

i have level 1 in javascript variable.
So i can't use selector direct.

Can anyone tell me how can i perform above.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your markup: valid parents for `<li>` elements cannot contain `<div>` or `<ul>` elements. Therefore, wrapping the `<span>` element in an `<li>` will give undefined results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap):

```
$( '.folder' ).wrap( '<li />' );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method for `.folder`. ex,

```
$("span.folder").wrap("<li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

the markup will be wrong but you can just run jquery [`.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) method on `.folder`-selector:

```
$(".folder").wrap("<li>");
```